# Poisson random variable conditioned on sum

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution

If $X_1,X_2...X_N$ are independent Poisson variables with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2...\lambda_3$, then given $\sum_iX_i=N$, we have that

$X_i \sim \mathrm{Binom}(N,\frac{\lambda_i}{\sum_j\lambda_j})$ (straight from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Related_distributions)!)

I am looking for a proof of this -- I haven't really studied the relevant stats to know how to attack  this problem. Any help would be great. Cheers!

Comment: I gave a derivation for 2 Poisson variables [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88588/regression-model-for-proportion-or-count-when-counts-of-outcome-and-total-events/88690#88690). Note that the binomial distribution is conditional on the realized value of the random variable $N$, usually written as $n$.

Comment: @Scortchi A derivation for two is good enough: it immediately implies the result for all $N\ge 2$.